# Replace end tag with value from opening tag

Tags: xml, replace, sed

for some reason, many of XML files I use for certain purposes, are now having the following structure:

```
<A1333>006</ANDfoo>
<A45>RO0</ANDfoo>
<A5652>5486465465</ANDfoo>
<A173>TEST DUMMY</ANDfoo>
<A1805>34566000</ANDfoo>
<A3>FKK</ANDfoo>
<A2>FKK</ANDfoo>
<A2002></ANDfoo>
<A9903>CV0000</ANDfoo>
<A558>
               <B1>GHJ</B1>
               <B5>101010</B5>
</ANDfoo>
```

All end tags are now having the same value. How can I replace the value from end tag with the correct value from opening tag in order to have a valid XML again. I tried using sed but no succesfull result so far. Can you please give an example using sed to do such replacement?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you call these XML files when they are nothing of the kind?

Comment: They used to be XML files and now they need some corrections to become valid XMLs again.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/<\([^>]*\)>\([^<>]*\)<[^>]*>/<\1>\2<\/\1>/g;  \ # fix Tags ending on same line
        /^<[^\/>]*>$/h;                                 \ # Push single opening tag
        /^<\/[^>]*>$/{g;s/</<\//}'                        # Pop and fix single closing tag
```

This will fix tags start and end in the same line, as well as tags that contain one nesting level and that start and end on a separate line.

To get to this from an XML-oneliner you can use sed again:

```
sed -e 's/\(<\/[^>]*>\)\s*/\1\n/g'     \ # Break after closing tag
    | sed -e 's/>\s*\(<\w*>\)/>\n\1/g'   # Break before opening tag if not on beginning of line
```

Comment: All tags are actually in 1 single line, I just used pretty print to see it more clearly: <A1333>006</ANDfoo><A45>RO0</ANDfoo><A5652>5486465465</ANDfoo><A173>TEST DUMMY</ANDfoo><A1805>34566000</ANDfoo><A3>FKK</ANDfoo><A2>FKK</ANDfoo><A2002></ANDfoo><A9903>CV0000</ANDfoo><A558><B1>GHJ</B1><B5>101010</B5></ANDfoo>

Comment: @spiderpc: ok, incorporated that requirement. Still, for multi-level nesting you'll want to look for something other than `sed`.